# how to match links ended with port number

Tags: php, regex

How to match the following link structure that ended with port number

**Links like**

```
https://www.some_thing.com:13306
http://www.some_thing.com:13306
www.some_thing.com:13306
some_thing.com:13306
```

**Example**

```
$link1 = "http://www.some_thing.com:13306"; // will be true
$link2 = "http://www.some_thing.com/lol"; // will be false
```

so can anyone help me out for regular expression for matching such type of links since it based on `:` then followed by numbers might be the key for matching such type.

~ Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure - it should be as simple as `/:\d+$/`:

```
if (preg_match('/:\d+$/', $url)) {
    echo 'It has a port';
} else {
    echo 'It does not have a port';
}
```

**Autopsy:**

- `:` - a literal `:` character
- `\d+` - a digit matched 1 or more times
- `$` - the string MUST end here. There can be nothing between the last match and the end of the string

Answer (score 1):

This works too ;)

```
<?php
$link1 = "http://www.some_thing.com:13306";
if(is_numeric(array_pop(explode(':',$link1))))
{
echo "Valid URL";
}
else
{
echo "Illegal URL";
}
```